# Airflow email alert not format as expected

Tags: email, smtp, airflow

I am using "apache-airflow 2.1.2".
I am working on the Airflow email configuration, and I got this email format problem.

I have set the email subject template in airflow.cfg. The subject_template look like this:

```
[airflow] Pipeline  '{{ti.dag_id}}' '{{ti.task_id}}' has status {{ti.state}}. {% if ti.state=="failed" %}is CRITICAL{% else %}is OK{% endif %}
```

Therefore, if everything works fine, I will get an email from "airflow-alerts@mycompany.com" and the email subject will be like this:

```sql
[airflow] Pipeline my_dag my_task has status failed. is CRITICAL
```

When I use "airflow dags test" command, it works fine.

```
airflow dags test my_dag 2021-01-01
```

However, when I use the UI to unpause or use "airflow dags backfill" command,

```sql
airflow dags backfill my_dag -s 2021-01-01
```

the email format is as default(which is wrong) and it is sent from "airflow@example.com".

```
Airflow alert: <TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task 2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 [failed]>
```

I have checked the log and didn't see anything related to this.

I don't know why using different commands leads to different results.

I have the airflow.cfg as follows.

```
[email]

# Configuration email backend and whether to
# send email alerts on retry or failure
# Email backend to use
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

# Whether email alerts should be sent when a task is retried
default_email_on_retry = True

# Whether email alerts should be sent when a task failed
default_email_on_failure = True

subject_template = /path/to/my/template

[smtp]

# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = myhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Example: smtp_user = airflow
# Example: smtp_password = airflow
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow-alerts@mycompany.com
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_retry_limit = 5
```

I am stuck on this problem for quite a while. I hope you can give me any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not written which version of airflow you used. BTW. if it's 1.10 then you should migrate to 2 because Airflow 1.10 is end-of-life since June and will not receive any fixes any more.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm using airflow 2.1.2.

Comment: Can you please open an issue in GitHub issues with all details? That seems like a bug.